# Hadoop map reduce over totient sum

Tags: java, hadoop, cluster-computing

I am having a hard time using Hadoop map reduce to compute the sum of totient between two values.

For example, I would like to compute the sum of totient for `[1, 15000]`.
But as far as I understand the map-reduce deals with data that has something in common (a label).

I managed to understand the schema for that data:

```
doctor  23
doodle  34
doctor  2
doodle  5
```

Those are the occurrences of a word find in a given text.

Using a map reduce will link the values for a given word like this:

```
doctor [(23 2)]
doodle [(34 5)]
```

and then compute the sum of those values.

But regarding a totient sum we never have something in common like a cord in the above example. Given that Dataset:

```
DS1: 1 2 3 4 5 ..... 15000
```

Would it be possible to compute the sum of all the totient in the list using a map reduce architecture ?

Comment: MapReduce doesn't require reading a key (or what you call a common label). It's only purpose is to combine output to a shared reducer for that key

Answer (score 0):

If you have the numbers in text file, separated by spaces you can split them and sum in the mapper, something like this:

Mapper:

```
public class SumMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, IntWritable> {
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = Arrays.stream(value.toString().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

Job control:

```
public class LocalMapReduceRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf " + args[1]);

        Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration());

        job.setJobName("MR_runner");
        job.setJarByClass(LocalMapReduceRunner.class);

        job.setMapperClass(SumMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks @cricket_007 for suggestions.

Comment: You could also just sum the whole line in the mapper. Seems wasteful to split a line into multiple records. Also `new Text()` in the Mapper could just be a NullWritable since you don't need a key here